# How to bind crystal report with linq to entities Method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I am facing an error while binding crystal report to my class library's method using linq to entities.Please help me .Error is:DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.Following is my code.

```html
 ReportDocument CustomerReport = new ReportDocument();
            CustomerReport.Load(Server.MapPath("Sample.rpt"));
           IList<Customer> cs;
            cs = Databasebase.GetAllCustomers();
            CustomerReport.SetDataSource(cs);
            CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = CustomerReport;
            CrystalReportViewer2.DataBind();
```

it is working fine with ADO.Net code but i need it using entity framework..code of ADO.Net is :

```html
 dsCustomer dscs = new dsCustomer();
            string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string statement = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
            SqlDataAdapter daStatement = new SqlDataAdapter(statement, conn);
            daStatement.Fill(dscs._dsCustomer);
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("ViewCustomer.rpt"));
            rpt.SetDataSource(dscs);
            this.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Comment: Is this failing on SetDataSource or ReportSource or DataBind method?

Comment: on SetDataSource......it is working fine with ADO.Net code but my requirement is Entity Framework.